# Why is the Devel block displaying the Performance, Execute PHP and Switch User blocks?

Tags: 7, debugging, blocks

My Devel block is displaying the Performance, Switch Users and Execute PHP blocks as well in the sidebar, making it very unsightly and bloated as well.

I can't see what I could have done to cause that and wonder if it is due to some interaction with some third-party module.

What could have caused that?

EDIT: I hve added the code for the block to low. There seems to a lot of `admin-pane-xxxx` classes and IDs there, and I suspect it has something to do with Admin menu. I have also checked devel on other installations, and they don't display this behaviour. I have asked a [related question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/91690/is-there-a-means-for-telling-which-module-or-template-files-generated-a-block) regarding how to locate where code for a particular block is being generated.

```
<div class="block block-admin contextual-links-region collapsiblock-processed admin-processed" id="block-admin-devel">

    <h2 class="title collapsiblock"><a role="link" href="#">Devel</a></h2>
  <div class="contextual-links-wrapper contextual-links-processed"><a href="#" class="contextual-links-trigger">Configure</a><ul class="contextual-links"><li class="block-configure first last"><a href="/admin/structure/block/manage/admin/devel/configure?destination=admin/structure/block">Configure block</a></li>
</ul></div>
  <div class="content">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" id="admin-block-devel-form" method="post" action="/admin/structure/block"><div><div class="admin-panes clearfix  processed">

          <div class="admin-pane admin-pane-active admin-pane-performance">
        <h2 class="admin-pane-title"><a class="admin-pane-active active" href="/admin/structure/block#admin-pane-performance">Performance</a></h2>
        <div class="admin-pane-content clearfix"><div class="item-list"><ul><li class="dev-timer first"><div class="dev-info"></div></li>
<li class="dev-memory-usage last"><div class="dev-info"></div></li>
</ul></div></div>
      </div>
                <div class="admin-pane  admin-pane-switch_user">
        <h2 class="admin-pane-title"><a class=" active" href="/admin/structure/block#admin-pane-switch_user">Switch user</a></h2>
        <div class="admin-pane-content clearfix"><ul class="links clearfix"><li class="1 first"><a title="This user can switch back." href="/devel/switch/admin?destination=admin/structure/block&amp;token=D1XQMmu5YkZ3s5fmg1HjPNbpJEWdfz9BkeIjQPjFqDg"><strong><em class="placeholder">admin</em></strong></a></li>
<li class="3"><a title="Caution: this user will be unable to switch back." href="/devel/switch/seetop?destination=admin/structure/block&amp;token=4zXMi8I2marB9l1FMwGzbC9845NRnmLqEFe_7pC4HGE">seetop</a></li>
<li class="2 last"><a title="Caution: this user will be unable to switch back." href="/devel/switch/c3pio?destination=admin/structure/block&amp;token=FPTt2bcUUJr8YYRwD4mcoliAWNijuZ79sqZaFoz3Hgs">c3pio</a></li>
</ul><div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-username" role="application">
 <input type="text" class="form-text form-autocomplete" maxlength="60" size="16" value="" name="username" id="edit-username" autocomplete="OFF" aria-autocomplete="list"><input type="hidden" class="autocomplete autocomplete-processed" disabled="disabled" value="https://cc5.rca2.net/user/autocomplete" id="edit-username-autocomplete">
<div class="description">Enter username</div>
<span aria-live="assertive" class="element-invisible" id="edit-username-autocomplete-aria-live"></span></div>
<input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Switch" name="op" id="edit-submit--3"></div>
      </div>
                <div class="admin-pane  admin-pane-execute">
        <h2 class="admin-pane-title"><a class=" active" href="/admin/structure/block#admin-pane-execute">Execute PHP</a></h2>
        <div class="admin-pane-content clearfix"><div class="form-item form-type-textarea form-item-code">
  <label for="edit-code">PHP code to execute </label>
 <div class="form-textarea-wrapper resizable textarea-processed resizable-textarea"><textarea class="form-textarea" rows="20" cols="60" name="code" id="edit-code"></textarea><div class="grippie"></div></div>
<div class="description">Enter some code. Do not use <code>&lt;?php ?&gt;</code> tags.</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="Execute" name="op" id="edit-op"></div>
      </div>
                <div class="admin-pane  admin-pane-menu">
        <h2 class="admin-pane-title"><a class=" active" href="/admin/structure/block#admin-pane-menu">Other tools</a></h2>
        <div class="admin-pane-content clearfix"><ul class="menu"><ul class="menu"><li class="first leaf"><a title="Helper functions, pages, and blocks to assist Drupal developers. The devel blocks can be managed via the block administration page." href="/devel/settings">Devel settings</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a title="Clear the CSS cache and all database cache tables which store page, node, theme and variable caches." href="/devel/cache/clear?destination=admin/structure/block">Empty cache</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a title="View entity information across the whole site." href="/devel/entity/info">Entity info</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a title="Execute some PHP code" href="/devel/php">Execute PHP Code</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a title="View fields information across the whole site." href="/devel/field/info">Field info</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a title="View a list of currently defined user functions with documentation links." href="/devel/reference">Function reference</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a title="View the active form/render elements for this site." href="/devel/elements">Hook_elements()</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a title="Details about a given menu item." href="/devel/menu/item?path=admin/structure/block">Menu item</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a title="View your server's PHP configuration" href="/devel/phpinfo">PHPinfo()</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a title="Rebuild menu based on hook_menu() and revert any custom changes. All menu items return to their default settings." href="/devel/menu/reset?destination=admin/structure/block">Rebuild menus</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a title="Run hook_uninstall() and then hook_install() for a given module." href="/devel/reinstall?destination=admin/structure/block">Reinstall modules</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a href="/devel/run-cron">Run cron</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a title="List the contents of $_SESSION." href="/devel/session">Session viewer</a></li>
<li class="leaf"><a title="View a list of available theme functions across the whole site." href="/devel/theme/registry">Theme registry</a></li>
<li class="last leaf"><a title="Edit and delete site variables." href="/devel/variable?destination=admin/structure/block">Variable editor</a></li>
</ul></ul></div>
      </div>


  </div>
<input type="hidden" value="form-9uJFBQ4hH879iRN_QBUrp46oNTDoops6Xvd5qoDSHkw" name="form_build_id">
<input type="hidden" value="hAmptoPteO_NNJXwFsRyruXJkKuh5LEmMFGxvtEqAkQ" name="form_token">
<input type="hidden" value="admin_block_devel_form" name="form_id">
</div></form>  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite clear what is the problem; where else do you see those links? Also if you believe it's an issue caused by some other module, you should tell something about the site setup itself.

Comment: What were you expecting the Devel block to show? Or were you not expecting to have a Devel block at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the [Admin](http://drupal.org/project/admin) module adds an additional `enhanced` block that combines those blocks into one, which is called `Devel` and I was activating it instead of using the Devel modules own blocks

Answer (score 0):

Go to Structure >> Blocks and disable those blocks from your sidebar region