# Is there a means for telling which module or template files generated a block?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks, blocks, files

I am trying to find out what code generated a [faulty looking devel block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/90724/why-is-the-devel-block-displaying-the-performance-execute-php-and-switch-user-b) and want to know if there is a module that can tell where a block was generated or some other means.

Is there a module for that, something like the [Module Summary](http://drupal.org/project/module_summary), but with info on blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't greatly overwritten the default block.tpl.php, you can tell by looking at the HTML attributes of the block DIV, which follow this naming convention:

```
<div id="block-MODULENAME-DELTA" class="block block-MODULENAME">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: In the example block referenced above the divs seem to belong to some `admin-pane` class but it is hard to tell if it is `admin menu` or Drupal's main `admin`? Could you take a look? I can't recollect any `admin pane` type of block.

Comment: All those DIVs are part of the block content. The block wrapper has an ID="block-admin-devel". The block is being created by the contrib Admin module, and the particular block is the one that Admin module calls "devel".

Comment: see https://drupal.org/project/admin

Comment: You were right about Admin module. It appears to create a combined version of the devel modules blocks and that was causing the problem. Thanks